# Automatic numbering in multiple documents

Tags: numbering, best-practices

When typesetting something like exercise sheets, I have a seperate document for every sheet (because of performance reasons while compiling; sometimes also because I compile some sheets not with pdflatex for example because of pstricks graphics).

Now I have a number in the header of each sheet (say sheet 1, sheet 2 etc).

Up to now I type the numbers manually. However is there a good practice to have latex to do this automatically?

Comment: Do you know the package `pdfpages`? I would do a master document where you include all the normal pages as usual and the pstrick-pages via `pdfpages`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Yes, but there's still no numbering with `pdfpages` ;-) I would suggest to define an environment, which imports the external document and automatically steps the 'exercise' (or whatever you call it) counter

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The problem is the numbering. Can this be done with pdfpages? In some way wrapped around it, don't know...

Comment: Please try `\includepdf[pagecommand={}]{somepage.pdf}` which should insert your pdf in full size and print a number on the default location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a wrapper command (or environment, but a command is easier here.)

`\importsheet` takes two arguments. The first optional one is meant for the options to be given to `\includepdf` (there are a lot of possible options, I preset some already in the call to `\includepdf`, but those can be reset with individual settings using the first argument. 
The second argument contains the name of the file. It's assumed that the extension is `.pdf`, so omit the extension.

An additional counter `sheets` is ref-stepped internally and can be referenced too then.

Please note that the geometries of importing and imported documents should be the same -- my values are just guesses.

**Really important** 
Anything what should be done additionally on the sheet of paper, must be specified with `pagecommand={...}` as an option to `\includepdf`. More sophisticated settings should be wrapped in an outside macro and given to `pagecommand=...` then.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{sheet}

\newcommand{\importsheet}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{sheet}%
  \IfFileExists{#2.pdf}{%
    \includepdf[pagecommand={{\Large \bfseries Sheet \thesheet}\thispagestyle{empty}},noautoscale=true,scale=0.9,#1]{#2.pdf}
  }{%
    Sorry, not available
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\importsheet[pages=21]{mysource}
\importsheet[pages=25]{mysource}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Due to lazyness I imported from my worksheet documents  -- the sheets there already have a separate header ;-)